# Why i am getting repeated values? Sometimes same value 3 times in a row?

Tags: c#

What I did is that, at the top of the Form1 I added a new int variable moveCounter.
In the constructor I start the variable with 0. moveCounter = 0;

In the pictureBox1 paint event, I did: moveCounter++;
And also in the paint event, I put the moveCounter values into a textBox:

```
private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            SolidBrush brush;
            Pen p=null;
           Point connectionPointStart;
           Point connectionPointEnd;
           Graphics g = e.Graphics;
           g.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;

               brush = new SolidBrush(Color.Red);
               p = new Pen(brush);
               for (int idx = 0; idx < wireObject1._point_X.Count; ++idx)
               {
                   Point dPoint = new Point((int)wireObject1._point_X[idx], (int)wireObject1._point_Y[idx]);
                   dPoint.X = dPoint.X - 5; // was - 2
                   dPoint.Y = dPoint.Y - 5; // was - 2
                   Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(dPoint, new Size(10, 10));
                   g.FillEllipse(brush, rect);    
               }

               for (int i = 0; i < wireObject1._connectionstart.Count; i++)
               {    
                   int startIndex = wireObject1._connectionstart[i];
                   int endIndex = wireObject1._connectionend[i];
                   connectionPointStart = new Point((int)wireObject1._point_X[startIndex], (int)wireObject1._point_Y[startIndex]);
                   connectionPointEnd = new Point((int)wireObject1._point_X[endIndex], (int)wireObject1._point_Y[endIndex]);
                   p.Width = 4;
                   g.DrawLine(p, connectionPointStart, connectionPointEnd);
                   moveCounter++;
                   textBox1.Text = moveCounter.ToString();
               }
        }
```

At the top of Form1, I created a variable of StreamWriter w; and in the constructor I did:

```
w = new StreamWriter(@"d:\movesCounter.txt");
```

In the pictureBox1 mouse move event, I check that only if moveCounter is above 10, then write the values to a text file.

```
private void pictureBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (mouseMove == true)
            {
                mouseDrag = true;
                Point NewPoint = e.Location;                    
                    wireObject1.MovePoint(selectedIndex, NewPoint, NewPoint); // when moving a point dragging the other point is vanished deleted. To check why !

                    label1.Text = "{X = " + NewPoint.X + "}" + " " + "{Y = " + NewPoint.Y + "}";
                    refreshFlag = true;
                    timer2.Start();

                    if (moveCounter > 10)
                    {
                        w.WriteLine("Number Of Moves ===>   " + moveCounter);
                    }
            }
            else
            {
                label19.Text = "{X = " + e.X + "}" + " " + "{Y = " + e.Y + "}";
            }
        }
```

In the pictureBox1 mouse up event i close the StreamWriter:

```
private void pictureBox1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (mouseMove == true)
            {
                Point NewPoint = e.Location;
                wireObject1._point_X[(int)selectedIndex] = NewPoint.X;
                wireObject1._point_Y[(int)selectedIndex] = NewPoint.Y;
                mouseMove = false;
                if (moveCounter > 10)
                {
                    w.Close();
                }
                WireObjectCoordinatesCloneFrame();
            }
    }
```

What I want to do is to record/write the values of moveCounter to the text file.
I put the moveCounter++; in the paint event in the bottom loop this loop work when two or more points are connected by line/s, and when I move one of the connected points around the pictureBox area client, I see in realtime the moveCounter values going up.

The problem is that in the text file on my hard disk the results I am getting are like this:

```
Number Of Moves ===>   11
Number Of Moves ===>   11
Number Of Moves ===>   11
Number Of Moves ===>   12
Number Of Moves ===>   12
Number Of Moves ===>   12
Number Of Moves ===>   13
Number Of Moves ===>   13
Number Of Moves ===>   13
Number Of Moves ===>   14
Number Of Moves ===>   14
Number Of Moves ===>   14
Number Of Moves ===>   15
Number Of Moves ===>   15
Number Of Moves ===>   16
Number Of Moves ===>   16
Number Of Moves ===>   17
Number Of Moves ===>   17
Number Of Moves ===>   18
Number Of Moves ===>   18
Number Of Moves ===>   19
Number Of Moves ===>   19
Number Of Moves ===>   20
Number Of Moves ===>   20
Number Of Moves ===>   20
Number Of Moves ===>   21
Number Of Moves ===>   21
Number Of Moves ===>   21
```

I can't figure out why I am getting some of the values two and even three times in a row like 20 20 20 or 21 21 21 or 18 18, instead to get each value once.

This is in the value 169. I wanted to add this passed 5 seconds, it's ok, but again the value 169 appears few times instead once. And it's the same like this in all the text file.

```
Number Of Moves ===>   169
Passed 5 Seconds ===>   5
Number Of Moves ===>   169
```

What can be the solution ?

EDITED**

This is the pictureBox1 mouse down event where i set the mouseMove bool variable to true so maybe the problem is somehwere here.

```
private void pictureBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
            {
                label1.Visible = true;
                label4.Visible = true;




                float t = wireObject1.GetIndexByXY(e.X, e.Y, 5);

                if (t == -1)
                {
                    button3.Enabled = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    button3.Enabled = true;
                    {
                        selectedIndex = t;
                        mouseMove = true;
                        OriginalX = wireObject1._point_X[(int)selectedIndex];
                        OriginalY = wireObject1._point_Y[(int)selectedIndex];



                        if (cyclicSelectedIndex.Count() == 2)
                        {

                            cyclicSelectedIndex[currentCyclicIndex] = (int)selectedIndex;
                            currentCyclicIndex++;
                            if (currentCyclicIndex == 2)
                            {
                                currentCyclicIndex = 0;
                            }


                            if ((cyclicSelectedIndex[0] == cyclicSelectedIndex[1]) || (cyclicSelectedIndex[0] == -1) || (cyclicSelectedIndex[1] == -1))

                            {
                                button2.Enabled = false;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                button2.Enabled = true;
                            }

                            for (int i = 0; i < wireObject1._connectionstart.Count; i++) 
                            {
                                if ((wireObject1._connectionstart[i] == cyclicSelectedIndex[0] && wireObject1._connectionend[i] == cyclicSelectedIndex[1]) ||
                                   (wireObject1._connectionstart[i] == cyclicSelectedIndex[1] && wireObject1._connectionend[i] == cyclicSelectedIndex[0]) ||
                                    wireObject1._connectionstart[i] == cyclicSelectedIndex[0] || wireObject1._connectionend[i] == cyclicSelectedIndex[1] ||
                                     wireObject1._connectionstart[i] == cyclicSelectedIndex[1] || wireObject1._connectionend[i] == cyclicSelectedIndex[0])
                                {

                                    button3.Enabled = false;
                                }

                                if ((wireObject1._connectionstart[i] == cyclicSelectedIndex[0] && wireObject1._connectionend[i] == cyclicSelectedIndex[1]) ||
                                   (wireObject1._connectionstart[i] == cyclicSelectedIndex[1] && wireObject1._connectionend[i] == cyclicSelectedIndex[0]))
                                {
                                    button2.Enabled = false;  
                                }
                            }

                            label13.Text = selectedIndex.ToString();
                            label13.Visible = true;
                            label14.Visible = true;
                            listView1.Items.Add(selectedIndex.ToString()).EnsureVisible();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Another thing is i added a timer to the designer Timer1.
The timer is enabled and set to 30 miliseconds.

In the pictureBox mouse move event i did:

```
refreshFlag = true;
```

Then in the timer1 tick event i check if this flag is true then make a pictureBox1.refresh();
The idea was to make the paint event only each 30 miliseconds when i drag/move a point connected or not connected in the move event. So maybe the problem is there ?

This is the timer1 tick event:

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (refreshFlag == true)
            {
                pictureBox1.Refresh();
                refreshFlag = false;
            }
        }
```

Comment: I would say the mouseMoveEvent (Write to file) is fired more often then paintEvent (increment moves)

Comment: webber2k6 could be i will add to my question the pictureBox mouse down event maybe the problem is there since there i make mouseMove to be true. But in general i dont have any idea yet how to solve it.

Comment: The Paint even is fired whenever Windows feels like it. A very bad place for setting moveCounters and TextBoxes. Rethink and redesign your logic.

Comment: If you are counting the MouseMoves, why don't you increment mouseMove in the MouseMove handler?

Comment: Solved by moving the mouseMove++ and the textBox1 from the paint event to the move event. Now its working good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `pictureBox1_MouseMove` is called more often than your `pictureBox1_Paint`, because the second one is only called every 30 ms and if the mouse was moved befor.

So increment your moveCounter where the mouse is moved:

```
private void pictureBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    ...
    moveCounter++;
    textBox1.Text = moveCounter.ToString();
    ...
}
```